# Jsoup parse to get text including greater than (>) and less than (<) symbol

Tags: jsoup

There is text in html like `<a>"There is a nothing special <<string>> haha"</a>`.

I want to get complete text including `<<` and `>>`, so the output want to look like `There is a nothing special <<string>> haha`.

I had done

```
Elements e = element.select("a");
String text = e.text();
```

but the output is `There is a nothing special <> haha`.

If print the `e.html()`, it would be

```
There is a nothing special &lt;
<string>
&gt;haha
</string>
```

How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The input is not valid HTML. jsoup follows the rules defined in the HTML5 specification on how to parse such non-conforming input. What you end up with is what you see as output of `e.html()`.
This transformation is lossy and there's no way to retrieve the original input when using jsoup.

Side note: The string `There is a nothing special <<string>> haha` should be encoded like this in an HTML document: `There is a nothing special &lt;&lt;string&gt;&gt; haha`